# Using arrays to read and write from fstream?

Tags: c++11

MAXSIZE set to 100, first menu option is supposed to check if there is size in the array, read from file and write to first slot of title[] array. I am quite lost.

```
switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
                while (getline(infile) < MAXSIZE)
                void readMovies(ifstream &infile, int year[], string title[], int &size){
                        string tmp_title;
                        int tmp_year;
                        while (getline(infile, tmp_title)
                        {
                            infile >> tmp_year;
                            infile.ignore();
                            year [size] = tmp_year;
                            title[size] = tmp_title;
                            size++;
                        }
        break;}
```

Comment: Guess what? I cannot compile this code. Go read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also you need to post what is the error and the observed behavior. Also you need to create a [MRE]

Comment: @bolov, the title looks like a question (maybe _How can I use_ instead of _Using_ would be better. But I agree with the missing MRE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a MWE of how to copy from a file to another file

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
int main() {
  std::ifstream ifs("input");
  std::ofstream ofs("output");
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ifs),
            std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(ofs, ", "));
}
```

Given the file `input` with content `1 2 3 4 5`, the `output` file will be filled with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`.